# php preg_match function 3rd parameter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I was reading the online manual of the preg_match function and wrote up a piece of code to test it. Along with it I wrote up another piece of code using `preg_grep`.

Here is the code:

```
$subject = array("Robert");
$subject2 = "Robert";
$pattern = "/./";


$result = preg_grep($pattern, $subject);
$result2 = preg_match($pattern, $subject2, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

For the `preg_grep` I got what I expected, an array element[0] with the value "Robert", that made sense.

For `preg_match` I got an unexpected result, at least to my understanding of regexp. It was an array element[0] with the value "R".

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` matches any character except new line. So it would return first character since `+` isn't present.

Answer (score 2):

Because `/./` means one character, not all. You should use a quantifier:

- `*` means 0 or more characters
- `+` means 1 or more characters
- `?` means 0 or 1 character

If you suffix quantifiers with `?` it means an ungreedy match (which means that it tries to match as less characters as possible, and not as much characters as possible).

A complete result:

```
Input string: 'Robert'

Regex    Result
=====    ======

/.*/     Robert
/.*?/    null
/.+/     Robert
/.+?/    R
/.?/     R
/.??/    null
```